# Getting the fulll path of an included file in the Makefile

Tags: makefile

A Makefile contains

```
include ../../common/common.mk
```

at the end of the file. I want to see the full path during the invocation. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(info full path to common.mk: $(abspath ../../common/common.mk))
include ../../common/common.mk
```

Usually, **make** does not change working directory during execution. Most likely, you can check for `../../common/common.mk` from command line just before running **make*. But if you use `make -C some/directory` then the working directory will be whatever you specify after `-C` (relative to your current directory).